# Is there way to use If condition inside a find command with option exec?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find

scenario: There are multiple files in an folder, I'm trying to find specific set of files and if a given file has specific info then I need to grep the information.

Ex:

```
find /abc/test \( -type f -name 'tst*.txt' -mtime -1 \) -exec grep -Po '(?<type1).*(?=type1|(?<=type2).*(?=type2)' {} \;
```

I need to include if condition along with find -exec (if grep is true then print the above)

```
if grep -q 'case=1' <filename>; then
    grep -Po '(?<type1).*(?=type1|(?<=type2).*(?=type2)'
fi
```

Thanks

Comment: So you need to process each file separately?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `-exec` in `find` as a condition -- the file matches if the command returns a successful exit code. So you can write:

```
find /abc/test -type f -name 'tst*.txt' -mtime -1 -exec grep -q 'case=1' {} \; -exec grep -Po '(?<type1).*(?=type1|(?<=type2).*(?=type2)' {} \;
```

Tests in `find` are evaluated left-to-right, so the second `grep` will only be executed if the first one was successful.

If your conditions are more complicated, you can put the whole shell code into a script, and execute the script with `-exec`. E.g. put this in `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if grep -q 'case=1' "$1"; then
    grep -Po '(?<type1).*(?=type1|(?<=type2).*(?=type2)' "$1";
fi
```

and then do:

```
find /abc/test -type f -name 'tst*.txt' -mtime -1 -exec ./myscript.sh {} \;
```

Comment: Might iterate over `"$@"` in the shell script -- then you could use `-exec ./myscript {} +` and reduce the number of invocations. Can do the same on the right-hand side of the two-exec approach, also.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to keep the answer simple.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PCRE option `-P` in `grep` you can combine both searches into one `grep` as well using lookahead:

```
find /abc/test -type f -name 'tst*.txt' -mtime -1 -exec grep -Po '(?=.*case=1).*\K((?<=type1).*(?=type1)|(?<=type2).*(?=type2))' {} +
```

btw the regex shown in your question is invalid, that I've tried to correct it here.